# Why to tell a reason when editing a post

Tags: discussion, edits, recommendation-questions

Since I haven't seen any really big questions and the fact that when I watch the edits the interesting parts are highlighted, I wonder who is *really* reading the "Edit Summary" and especially why I should write something into it.

Answer (score 4):

The edit summary is the place you justify your edit. For example in an edit that changes this code

```
if [$a -eq $b ]
```

to this

```
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
```

I would write an edit summary like

> The `[` needs spaces bofore and after, added quotes to prevent word splitting.

This explains to future readers why the edit is valid.

Especially when making a *suggested* edit, it is important to convince the reviewers that your edit is correct, otherwise they might reject it as invalid. The edit summary is a perfect place for that.

Comment: isn't it clear when watching it? and if so shouldn't it be explained in the context then instead of somewhere "hidden"?

Comment: The reson for the edit is not always clear without the message.

Comment: And, the edit reason is shown at the very top of the suggested edit, so it's (likely) the very first thing the reviewer sees.